# ubuntu "make" error : hg: not found

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to 'make' a project with ubuntu.
I get this error :

```
sh: 1: hg: not found
make[3]: *** [/home/user/myproject/build/CMakeFiles/stamp/eigen3-download] Error 127
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/eigen3.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [externals] Error 2
```

What is the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: projects usually have an install or readme file or a homepage where you can see the dependencies you have to install in order to build it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need Mercurial. Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

Comment: Thank you . Now I have another error : Could NOT find Java (missing:  Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE)

Comment: Check if you have installed `java`. If not install with `apt-get install java`. If this does not work try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19908614/1288306).

Comment: THANK YOU MAN. and this one ? cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’

Comment: I suspect that your version of C++ compiler (G++) does not support C++ 11 standard. You need to upgrade G++.