# Set custom Java version for CMake

Tags: java, cmake, scidb

I am trying to install a Tool (SciDB); its installing procedure makes use of CMake. At a certain point it requires Java 1.8, which is not installed on the system.

```
-- Could NOT find Java (missing:  Java_JAVA_EXECUTABLE Java_JAR_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAC_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVAH_EXECUTABLE Java_JAVADOC_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Error at src/jdbc/CMakeLists.txt:5 (message):
  Java 1.8 is currently the only supported version for building JDBC!
```

I installed it somewhere in my home folder; how to tell CMake to use my version?

I tried to set the `$JAVA_HOME` and `$PATH` variable as suggested  [in this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908262/cmake-cant-find-java-but-its-installed), but got no results.

Comment: According to `FindJava.cmake` script, setting `JAVA_HOME` environment variable should work. ([Referenced answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908262/cmake-cant-find-java-but-its-installed) sets this variable, but doesn't `export` it. Probably, this is a problem). What CMake version you use?

Answer (score 0):

SciDB uses its own version of FindJava.cmake (located in `cmake/Modules/FindJava.cmake`). SciDB expects a particular environment and that the user has installed OpenJDK version 1.8.

One way to use your JAVA_HOME is to modify `cmake/Modules/FindJava.cmake` in your source code and add your `${JAVA_HOME}/bin`:

```
    set(_JAVA_PATHS
        $ENV{JAVA_HOME}/bin
        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin
        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin
        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin
    )
```

**NOTE**: The version of Java in that `$JAVA_HOME` will ***NOT*** be checked.